# Переопределить функцию в Laravel из директории vendor

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Использую в проекте на Laravel админку Sleeping Owl, вылетает ошибка, я нашел [фикс](https://github.com/Pingvi/SleepingOwlAdmin/commit/8d3c9d0d17021bed8c8fc5665e13918ca011cf03). Но исправлять, естественно, приходится в директории vendor. Сайт лежит на впске и разворачивать заново удобно с помощью git, но каждый раз приходится вносить правки в vendor. Подскажите как правильно переопределить функцию из vendor, не залезая в него. Это вообще возможно и правильно?

Comment: Раз фикс внесен может просто надо сделать composer update совы до той в которой есть фикс ?

Answer (score 2):

Всегда можно вспомнить ООП в том месте, где подгружаете класс вендора подгружайте свой.
убрать `use VendorClass;`
добавить `use MyClass;`

в файле MyClass переопределите метод да и все...

```
use VendorClass;
class MyClass extends VendorClass{
  public vendorMethod(){}
}
```

Comment: найти бы еще, где он подгружается, этот класс